# Jquery $.post - From server to client - how does it knows what response to get?

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

So we have this:

```
$.post('testeUpdate.php', 'someValue'
        function(dadosResposta) {
            $('#ns-nome').val(dadosResposta.nsName);
            $('#ns-endereco').val(dadosResposta.nsAddress);
        },
"json");
```

From client to server:
Is sends 'sameValue' to testeUpdate.php using POST.

On success, it receives the data returned by the server side script and do something with that on the client side. Correct?

There is something between the Server Side script and this Client Side script that I'm not getting.

Question:
**How does dadosResposta gets filled with the data returned from the serverside script ?
How does it knows? How does it work?**
Perhaps the question may also be posed: how do jquery knows when something is "on success" ?

Or trying on another way:
The server side executes the script, returns some encoded data in json. Until here ok. After this, what happens? How do we jump into the client side part again?

[update]
Trying again:
I know that: **dadosResposta contains whatever the server-side script returns** my question is, **HOW** does it knows about that? How does he do that?
[/update]

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `.post` function uses an XMLHttpRequest object to access the URL you passed to it. The server responds with either a `200 OK` (success) or some other response (presumably failure).

On success, the XMLHttpRequest object has its `responseText` (or `responseXML`) property set to the data returned by the server. The behind-the-scenes jQuery function that handles the response then looks at your `dataType` argument to determine what to do with the returned data. In the case of your example, it attempts to parse it into an object.

Assuming the response is a valid JSON string, it then passes that newly created object to your callback function as its first (and only) argument, which you've named `dadosResposta`.

*That* is how jQuery gets your data into `dadosResposta`.

**Edit:**
Here's some code that's probably vaguely akin to what's going on:

```
$.post = function([arguments])
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // not cross browser compatible, but good enough for demonstration
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)
        {
            switch (your_dataType)  // check your data type
            {
                case 'json':
                    your_callback(json_decode(xhr.responseText));    // call your function with JSON object
                    break;
                case 'xml':
                    your_callback(xhr.responseXML);    // call your function with XML
                case ... (etc)
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.open('POST', your_URL, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: What part in my code have made you make this assumption: "In the case of your example, it attempts to parse it into an object." ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your last argument to `$.post` is `json`. This means the function will assume the server returns a JSON string, which jQuery will then parse into an object (assuming it's a valid JSON string).

Comment: thanks for the details provided. It has help me to start to understand what's going on here. :D

Comment: Always glad to help! (Also, here's some more info on the XMLHttpRequest object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` takes a callback function. That callback takes one argument, which is the data returned from the server. So, in your case, `dadosResposta` is the data returned from the server.

It knows whether it was successful or not because of the status code in the HTTP header returned (`200 OK` in this case). You can include a second argument in your callback which will contain the status.

**EDIT:** It knows because that's how jQuery works. jQuery gets the response, and passes it as a parameter to your callback. If you want to know more about the internals, read up on [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: thanks a lot. please note my [update] part on the initial question. And thanks for the additional header info.

Comment: "It knows because that's how jQuery works"... Naaa. That's not an answer is it? :p 

However, the XMLHttpRequest that it uses may seem to be the answer. 

I still don't know how does jquery does that. I know that somehow, it will use XMLHttpRequest, but no more then that. I guess I cannot have my answer here. And if I do, I will probably not get it at once.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I don't mean to offend, but I feel like I have a pretty good explanation of what's going on just below.

Comment: @MEM The reason I said "because that's how it works" is because you were asking "how it knows". That's a bit like asking how JavaScript "knows" that you want `x` to be `3` when you say `x = 3`. It knows because that's how it works; that's how JavaScript is defined. Maybe I should have said "it knows because that's how the function is defined".

Comment: @Skilldrick :) Even that would not be an answer... I would then ask: "How is the function defined, so that I could understand, how does it work?" :) Common, this is not a question of having patience or not. ;) 

I still have doubt's with Ryan Kinal answer, like: "And how XMLHttpRequest knows that? But that was not what I asked, so I keeped that doubt to myself. :)

Comment: @MEM You're delving deeper and deeper into the technology with each question! Once you know how XHR works you'll want to know how HTTP works, and then you'll want to know how TCP/IP works (after that it's turtles all the way down). The question, however, was how jQuery does it, and it does it with XHR :)

Comment: lol I don't like turtles and I doubt that they have the strength to support the all world. ;) But who knows... :)

Still, :p the question however is "how jQuery does it" and it does it in a way that we seem to not know, still, it USES XHR for doing that.

Analogous, we can know that the carpenter USES a saw for doing is job, but that doesn't give us the answer about HOW have he done that magnificent table. 

On my way to turtles,
Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in the callback function (`dadosResposta` in this case) contains whatever the server-side script returns. For example, if the server side script was just returning the word "completed" in plain text, `dadosResposta` would be the string `"completed"`.

In this particular case, the data is JSON, which allows the data to be better organized so that specific fields can be accessed as in `dadosResposta.nsName`.

Comment: thanks a lot. please note my [update] part on the initial question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you asking how it knows to format it as JSON? The last parameter of `$.post()` is specified as "json", and I assume the Content-Type header of the server-side script would be `application/json`.

Comment: np DLH. It was a hard one to make anyway and I'm sorry for my poor capacities for clarification. :s Still, all ended well. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery knows the call was succesfull when the request returns a http status code of 200. If the server fails to process the request, an error code (ie 500) should be returned.

Comment: thanks a lot. please note my [update] part on the initial question.